# python range and string

Tags: python, range

I am trying to define a function `CountXSeconds` which for a given integer value X will create a string explaining what you need to say out loud when counting seconds. e.g.
`CountXSeconds(3)` should give the output 
“1 one thousand. 2 one thousand. 3 one thousand”
 This is the closest I got but I can't find a way to include the string "one thousand" without errors:

```
def main():
    CountXSeconds()


def CountXSeconds():
    n = int(input("What is your number?" ))
    if n >= 1:

        print(*range(1,n+1))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Do you want the string to print just "One one thousand", the common thing to say when counting seconds to get the length right. Or do you want it to print how to say eg. 1234 ? One thousand two hundred thirty four.

Comment: Can you please give me the name and phone number of the person who taught you this style so I can call them and inform them that Python is not C/C++?

Comment: Lol erm you'll have to excuse me i am still trying to learn Python! its a complete alien experience for me

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i,"one thousand.",end='')
print()
```

Comment: perfect :) thank you, this one i actully understand now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that solves your problem but is code-golfed enough to look weird as a homework answer at this level:

```
print(' '.join(map(lambda x: "%d one thousand." % x, range(1, n))))
```

Explanation!

- A "lambda function" is simply a very small way of writing a function without naming it. In this case, `lambda x: "%d one thousand." % x` will take in a number `x` and output the string `"1 one thousand"` if x=1, for example.
- The `%` operator used in that lambda is a shortcut for [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples). That's a bit too much to explain right now, but here it basically means "insert the value of `x` where the `%d` is".
- The `map` function is a fancy way of writing an entire `for` loop in a single line. It takes a function and a list, and applies the function to each item in the list.
- `' '.join` is a peculiarity of Python. What it does is take a list and turn it into a string by putting a space between each of the items. You would think that it'd be a function you call on the list, but in Python it's a function on the string instead.

Here's a much more clearly written version:

```
numbers = range(1, n)
make_count_string = lambda x: "%d one thousand." % x
count_strings = map(make_count_string, numbers)
combined_string = ' '.join(count_strings)
print(combined_string)
```

Comment: yes its one of the excises to try out on your own ,this one works but any chance you could give me an explanation to how you broke it down?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can use. It would be good to have better user input validation and more informative message according to the value that should be typed.

```
def count_x_seconds():
    n = input("What is your number: ")
    assert n.isdigit(), "What you entered is not a digit !"
    n = int(n)
    if n > 1:
        print(' '.join(map(lambda x: "%d one thousand." % x, range(1, n+1))))
```